# Usage of parentheses in Groovy method call

Tags: groovy

I started learning Groovy, and understood that parentheses are optional in method calls, so

```
   def list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
   list.each ({ item ->
     println "Item: $item"
   })
```

is the same as

```
   def list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
   list.each { item ->
     println "Item: $item"
   }
```

But now found this example

```
   def list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
   list.each() { item ->
     println "Item: $item"
   }
```

which also works. How is it possible to first call method with empty parameter list, and then specify closure after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a little different when closures are involved. There is a special facility for closures that occur as the last parameter ([as explained here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/11/groovy-goodness-passing-closures-to.html)).

As another illustration, consider:

```
class Foo {
    int bar(s, c) {
        return c(s)
    }

    int abc(c, s) {
        return c(s)
    }
}

def foo = new Foo()
def s = "fox"
```

This is a classic style:

```
assert 3 == foo.bar(s, { it.size() })
```

Yet this will work for closures as last argument:

```
assert 3 == foo.bar(s) { it.size() }
```

This is classic:

```
assert 3 == foo.abc({ it.size() }, s)
```

But this won't work

```
// assert 3 == foo.abc({ it.size() }) s
```

No doubt the reasoning is that if there is only one parameter, as with `List.each()`, then the syntax is very elegant:

```
list.each { item -> println item }
```